# Is the universal wave function expressible? How does it relate to energy in GR? What is it compatible with?

Tags: energy, cosmology, wavefunction

I am trying to wrap my mind around the universal wave function. Which doesn't seem like a clear concept to me.

Is there an actual equation which is *the* universal wave function or is it inferred from the equations in Everett's original writings on the topic?

Is there a relationship between E from GR, and the wave function? Is it the function of all energy from the beginning of the universe to the end of time?

If the many worlds interpretation was falsified, is a universal wave function still a viable concept? For example, is there room for a universal wave function if the universe ends and begins again as per conformal cyclic cosmology? What would the difference be between expressing the total sum history of all energy in the universe as a function, and the universal wave function?

As the universe unfolds, is the interpretation of the function probabilist IE multiple possible functions or is there one function?

I apologize if these questions are impetuous or too generalized.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a universal wave function, or wave function of the universe, is a fundamental misunderstanding of quantum mechanics which appeared implicit in de Broglie's 1924 suggestion, but was refuted when the mathematical structure of quantum mechanics was developed, in the "three-men’s paper" (Born, Heisenberg, and Jordan) and by Dirac in 1926. The [axiomatic formulation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%E2%80%93von_Neumann_axioms), developed by Dirac (1930) and von Neumann (1932) makes quite clear that qm describes probabilistic relationships between initial conditions and observed experimental results. This is quite distinct from material structure or "wave-particle duality" assumed in early formulations of the Copenhagen interpretation, and it means that there is no such thing as the wave function of the universe. The wave function of the universe has already been refuted, as has many worlds which does not respect other aspects of the mathematical structure of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Do you have references for the refutations of a universal wave function? Specifically the Hartle Hawking style wave function related to the Wheeler-DeWhitt equation. As far as I was aware, this was still an active field of research (at least, papers are still being published relating to this including by Hartle, but I'm not in the area).

Comment: Any decent mathematical treatment of quantum mechanics will make clear that the wave function is a way of calculating probabilities for measurement results given initial conditions. There is no reason for a specific refutation, because this is already clear and well understood by those who understand the mathematical structure of qm, and because it will never be understood by those who do not trouble to understand mathematical structure. I personally recommend Jauch, Foundations of Quantum Mechanics, but there are many other accounts.

Comment: There is most definitely a need for a refutation, citation or demonstration. Otherwise these are just words and aggrandisement of one's superior mathematics. I didn't come here to ask who is the best mathematician though... Instead I came here to learn something I didn't know, and I learned nothing from your assertions without evidence.

Comment: I have already cited the work of Born, Heisenberg, Jordan, Dirac and von Neumann, which defines quantum mechanics. This completely refutes ideas of "the wave function of the universe". People who talk of such things are not even talking of quantum mechancs, or indeed of anything in modern physics.

Comment: Also, the link is a dead link.

Comment: I don't know why the link was broken. I have fixed it.

Comment: @Charles Francis : None of that work could be considered a refutation of the idea because the idea came _AFTER_ their work. Everett published in 1957, some 31 years _later!_

Comment: @The_Sympathizer, as I said in the answer, Everett's idea was based on the pre-quantum theory of de Broglie, which was refuted by quantum mechanics once properly developed. It was *already* refuted before he talked about it. Unfortunately these misconceptions are often still taught today, but they only show that those teaching them, and Everett himself, did not understand quantum mechanics and were not talking about quantum mechanics or even about physics.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis, the de Broglie-Bohm interpretation is not refuted, and in fact Von Neumann was infamously found by Bell to have produced an incorrect refutation of it. Alas, Von Neumann was dead in 1957, so could not remark on developments after his death. I'm not endorsing the Everett interpretation myself, but this discussion would be best conducted by adducing evidence or detailed argument, not simply bald claims that the "mathematical structure" (whichever one is currently in vogue) rules something or other out.

Comment: @Steve, qm is not 2-dimensional, and this is not the place to discuss erroneous arguments by Bell or Bohmian mechanics.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis, then it wouldn't be the place to assert that they are erroneous either. It's certainly farfetched to claim that Everett "was not even talking about physics". It is also arrogant to claim that various physicists "have not troubled to understand the mathematical structure" - they almost certainly have troubled themselves to understand, whether they have arrived at a correct understanding or not.

Comment: @Steve, Not at all, since the physicists themselves do not even think that the mathematical structure should be understood and despise those who do study it.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis, I can't myself say I've ever encountered any hint, that there exist (or have existed) physicists who think mathematics should be purged from physics. There's certainly no evidence that de Broglie, Bohm, Bell, Einstein, Everett, or many others who have taken some sort of critical position about the ontology being employed by physicists, have fallen into that category. I think more often one encounters those who claim to understand the mathematics, but have a very hard time making themselves understood or expressing themselves in English. (1/2)

Comment: When such people do attempt to express in English, it is often done incorrectly or absurdly. At the very least, it becomes apparent that they are employing an ontology, that many sensible people would consider highly questionable, yet the holder employs it quite casually and tacitly as if there was never any question. When they are unequipped to address such questions, they tend to blame the other person for doing too little reading and learning, rather than accepting any blame themselves for having done too little, and having hitherto exposed themselves to too narrow a body of opinion. (2/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118289/discussion-between-charles-francis-and-steve).